# Rasa X to build a prototype only

Tags: rasa, rasa-nlu, rasa-x

I am new to Rasa and I would like to use Rasa X to build a prototype for my startup. Rasa X is only available for rasa enterprise users, do I need to be a paying customer just to use Rasa X?